# S3 Inventory: Include S3 Object Metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[AWS S3 Inventory documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) says the report contains corresponding metadata

> ... that list your objects and their corresponding metadata ...

However, I don't see any object metadata being exported in the dump csv file. I have some custom metadata added to the objects in my S3 bucket (x-amz-meta).

Do I have to enable some option somewhere to get the metadata in the report? Or did I misunderstood it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Amazon S3 Inventory reports do not include object-level metadata.

The only metadata available are those listed on that documentation page. Sadly, it does not include user-created metadata.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to build the tag into the key. Since the key is included in the inventory report (obviously), you can get the tag by splitting the key later.